# Base de datos Pre poblada con SQLite plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, cordova, android-sqlite

tengo el siguiente problema: 
estoy usando SQLite Plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlite en mi App híbrida con cordova versión: 6.1.1

Tengo una bd prepoblada ubicada en la carpeta www de mi proyecto y la conexión a mi bd la tengo así:

```
var _db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
        name: 'db_skulapp.db',
        location: 1,
        createFromLocation: 1
    },
    _function,
    function(_error){
        console.log('Error abriendo bd: '+JSON.stringify(_error));
    });
```

La conexión se abrio y no reporta error alguno, pero cuando realizo alguna consulta sobre la bd, me reporta el siguiente error:

> no such table: perfil (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO perfil
>   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Decidí imprimir el valor de tx(el objeto que se crea en el contexto de _db.transaction()) y este es su valor:

```
{"openargs":{"name":"db_skulapp.db","location":1,"createFromLocation":1,"dblocation":"libs","createFromResource":"1"},"dbname":"db_skulapp.db"}
```

**Pregunta:**

1. Como lo corrijo(obviamente)?
2. Como puedo verificar la ubicación y la estructura de la bd en mi dispositivo(es decir la ruta donde se almacena)?

Gracias a quien pueda ayudarme!

Comment: El plugin que referencias está marcado como obsoleto. En su lugar el recomendado es https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage. Estas usando crosswalk? En que plataforma te sale el error, Android? Este plugin está reportado presentar problemas en algunos casos así.

Comment: Saludos y gracias por tu comentario, en efecto erre la url, estoy usando el plugin que indicas, paso a responder tus preguntas:

1. Estas usando crosswalk? No
2. En que plataforma te sale el error, Android? Si solo estoy usando esa por ahora

Agradezco tu diligente ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien por que, pero el autor del plugin lo "partió" en distintas versiones y la que soporta bases de datos pre pobladas es [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext), prueba con esa.